# Cannot get VirtualBox machine's IP using the VBox API

Tags: c++, winapi, virtual-machine, virtualbox, invalid-argument

I have a VirtualBox machine with Ubuntu, that has a bridged adapter attached to it.

**What I'm trying to do is obtain the IP of the machine.**

If I start the machine manually and use the VBoxManage utility like this:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get "Ubuntu Test Machine" /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP
```

it works ok.

However, what I need is to obtain the IP programmatically using the VBox SDK.
Here's the most important part of the code (I'll post the whole code below at the end):

```
HRESULT hr = machine->GetGuestPropertyValue(L"/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP", &ip);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    printf("The machine's IP is: %s", ip);
}
else
    printf("Error retrieving machine IP! rc = 0x%x\n", hr);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error retrieving machine IP! rc = 0x80070057
```

Apparently that error code means **invalid parameter**.

**Can anyone tell me what's wrong with that parameter? Or if I'm doing something else wrong?**

Here's the whole code (it's basically the sample code from the VBox SDK sample directory with a few modifications):

```
int testStartVM(IVirtualBox *virtualBox)
{
    HRESULT rc;

    IMachine *machine = NULL;
    BSTR machineName = SysAllocString(L"Ubuntu Test Machine");

    rc = virtualBox->FindMachine(machineName, &machine);

    if (FAILED(rc))
    {
        // this code is verbose and not relevant
    }
    else
    {
        ISession *session = NULL;
        IConsole *console = NULL;
        IProgress *progress = NULL;
        BSTR sessiontype = SysAllocString(L"headless");
        BSTR guid;

        do
        {
            rc = machine->get_Id(&guid); /* Get the GUID of the machine. */
            if (!SUCCEEDED(rc))
            {
                printf("Error retrieving machine ID! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
                break;
            }

            /* Create the session object. */
            rc = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Session,        /* the VirtualBox base object */
                                  NULL,                 /* no aggregation */
                                  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, /* the object lives in a server process on this machine */
                                  IID_ISession,         /* IID of the interface */
                                  (void**)&session);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(rc))
            {
                printf("Error creating Session instance! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
                break;
            }

            /* Start a VM session using the delivered VBox GUI. */
            rc = machine->LaunchVMProcess(session, sessiontype,
                                          NULL, &progress);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(rc))
            {
                printf("Could not open remote session! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
                break;
            }

            /* Wait until VM is running. */
            printf("Starting VM, please wait ...\n");
            rc = progress->WaitForCompletion(-1);

            /* Get console object. */
            session->get_Console(&console);

            /* Bring console window to front. */
            machine->ShowConsoleWindow(0);

            // give it a few seconds just to be sure everything has been started
            Sleep(40 * 1000);
            BSTR ip;

            **// this line fails**
            HRESULT hr = machine->GetGuestPropertyValue(L"/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP", &ip);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                printf("The machine's IP is: %s", ip);
            }
            else
                printf("Error retrieving machine IP! rc = 0x%x\n", hr);

            printf("Press enter to power off VM and close the session...\n");
            getchar();

            /* Power down the machine. */
            rc = console->PowerDown(&progress);

            /* Wait until VM is powered down. */
            printf("Powering off VM, please wait ...\n");
            rc = progress->WaitForCompletion(-1);

            /* Close the session. */
            rc = session->UnlockMachine();

        } while (0);

        SAFE_RELEASE(console);
        SAFE_RELEASE(progress);
        SAFE_RELEASE(session);
        SysFreeString(guid);
        SysFreeString(sessiontype);
        SAFE_RELEASE(machine);
    }

    SysFreeString(machineName);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HRESULT rc;
    IVirtualBox *virtualBox;

    /* Initialize the COM subsystem. */
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    /* Instantiate the VirtualBox root object. */
    rc = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VirtualBox,       /* the VirtualBox base object */
                            NULL,                   /* no aggregation */
                            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,    /* the object lives in a server process on this machine */
                            IID_IVirtualBox,        /* IID of the interface */
                            (void**)&virtualBox);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(rc))
    {
        printf("Error creating VirtualBox instance! rc = 0x%x\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }

    listVMs(virtualBox);

    testStartVM(virtualBox);

    /* Release the VirtualBox object. */
    virtualBox->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Passing different string types to an API is odd. Does the `GetGuestPropertyValue` take a `const wchar_t*` as input and `BSTR*` as output? Where is the documentation for that interface?

Comment: First, you should check if the machine has started at all, second - have you tried polling? Maybe VBox responds in such a manner because the network stack is not up yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. Apparently the GetGuestPropertyValue function doesn't know how to automatically convert wchar_t* to BSTR. I need to give it an actual BSTR.

Here's the correct way:

```
BSTR val = SysAllocString(L"/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP");

HRESULT hr = machine->GetGuestPropertyValue(val, &ip);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    wprintf(L"The machine's IP is: %s", ip);
}
else
    printf("Error retrieving machine IP! rc = 0x%x\n", hr);

SysFreeString(val);
```

Comment: Nothing knows "how to automatically convert wchar_t* to BSTR"; this conversion would require you to be psychic, as a) `BSTR` has a very similar storage format to a C string but is not the same, and b) `BSTR` has its own allocator; mixing and matching is bad. And it could very well be that your COM object proxies to another process entirely; the RPC system needs a real `BSTR` to marshal, and that happens before VirtualBox's code even runs. You will always need to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: If you don't want to manually manage your `BSTR`s, use one of the wrapper classes, like [CComBSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx), or [_bstr_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx). This allows you to write code like this: `machine->GetGuestPropertyValue(CComBSTR(L"/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"), &ip)`.

Comment: Whenever you deal with COM interfaces, **all strings** must be real `BSTR`s, unless documented otherwise. `BSTR` is the only string type that COM natively knows about. The reason people get into trouble with this is because `BSTR` is defined as `WCHAR*` in `wtypes.h` for C/C++ compilers, so they can't perform proper type validation, thus allowing *any* wide string to be passed where a `BSTR` is expected, even though it is wrong. It is a shame that Microsoft never came up with a `STRICT`-like way to address this conflict.